# shouldChangeCharactersInRange not called from class inheriting from UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I know there are posts regarding shouldChangeCharactersInRange but none of them target my problem. So this Is what I am struggling with. I have a class kMoneyTextField which inherits from UITextField. I want to parse every character typed by user before I print it inside TextField. Unfortunatelly my shouldChangeCharactersInRange method is not being called - NEVER!

kMoneyTextField.h

```
@interface kMoneyTextField : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate>
@end
```

kMoneyTextField.m

```
@implementation kMoneyTextField

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder { 
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {        
        [self setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    // WHY NOBODY CALLS ME?!?
    return YES;
}
```

I am out of ideas and I really need this method to work. I am working with xcode 6.4 targeting ios7.0+. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Is `initWithCoder:` ever being called? Log it and see... If it isn't, you are never setting the delegate, which would explain why the delegate methods are not called.

Comment: Yes, It's being called because I also set there some other parameters and subscribe to events which work just fine.

Comment: By the way, what is `TRUE`? You really should be returning `YES` or `NO` here.

Comment: My bad, will fix that :)

Comment: Okay, try this: set a symbolic breakpoint on `setDelegate:`. I'm guessing that someone else is setting themselves as the delegate after you do it, thus pulling the delegate messages away from you.

Comment: Finally, I have one more suggestion: implement `awakeFromNib` and set the delegate there. What you are doing (calling a setter in an initializer) is kind of skanky. But there is nothing wrong with calling a setter in `awakeFromNib`. Don't forget to call `super` in your `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: I set the delegate inside awakeFromNib but It's not working. However, when I set a symbolic breakpoint on setDelegate: it is being called 7 times. So I checked where are those calls from and It appears that some external pods are calling setDelegate:self on my textFields. Does that mean that there can be only one delegate per instance?

Comment: Yes it does. :) So my little answer (my second answer) is right, if the pods are doing this to _this_ text field.

Comment: Ok, so what am I supposed to do now if two pods want to be delegates and I want one for my own?

Comment: You will have to rethink what you want. You cannot want this. It is impossible. You need to think more deeply about _why_ you think you need this text field to respond to `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`. But that is not what you asked! The question you asked has been answered.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that someone else is setting themselves as the delegate after you do it, thus pulling the delegate messages away from you.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but the other methods from `UITextFieldDelegate` are getting called, except for `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:`. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Ideally you don't want to assign a subclass of UITextField to be it's own delegate as this prevents anything that uses this subclass from being able to assign itself as delegate (or if they do it will result in unexpected behaviour). Thankfully UITextField has great set of notifications that you can connect into that mimic the delegate callbacks.

So to answer your question I would use something like this:

```
#pragma mark - Init

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(textChanged:)
                                                     name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:self];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Notifications

- (void)textChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
//Do what needs to be done here
}

#pragma mark - MemoryManagement

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

It's important to note that in Objective-C there is a convention of having a designated initializer which initializers pipe into, for UITextField I believe this is:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

Comment: "Ideally you don't want to assign a sub class of UITextField to be it's own delegate" No, there's nothing wrong with doing that. You are not explaining the issue the OP is seeing, you are just giving a different kind of advice (and that advice is wrong).

Comment: @matt, while you can of course assign a subclass of UITextFields as it's delegate, the OP goes on to state that they are then not getting the the callbacks - I believe this is because another object is then setting itself a delegate so "stealing" those callbacks. One alternative to this is using notifications to gain the same information as the delegate callback.

Comment: @matt I've updated the opening statement to better clarify my intent - which i notice you have included in an answer to this question

Comment: I didn't mean to steal your answer! I didn't grasp at all that you were implying that this is what _is_ happening. Let's see if the OP confirms this. You should have rewritten your answer more clearly. It is very hard to find my answer buried in your answer!

Comment: Also your answer is still full of false info. You should never call `init(frame:)` from `init(coder:)`.

Comment: @matt Having read my original answer back you where totally right that I was implying an issue and then stating an alternative implementation rather than stating what I thought the actual issue was - thanks for you feedback ;-)

Comment: @matt i never state that you should call "initWithFrame" from inside "initWithCoder"

Comment: "there is a convention of having a designated initializer which initializers pipe into" His initializer `init(coder:)` _is_ a designated initializer. His view comes from the storyboard. `init(frame:)` will _never_ be called _and he should not call it_, which is what you are (wrongly) telling him to do throughout your answer.

Comment: Another problem is that no mere notification can do what `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` does - you cannot return a BOOL from a notification and _prevent_ or _alter_ character entry.